# Default CSS shown briefly before CSS set with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to make a website that will have a dark and light theme, with a button/buttons to switch between them. I have it working so that the buttons will switch between the themes, and the save either 'dark' or 'light' in local storage, so that the theme will be consistent between pages and page refreshes. I have some javascript that runs when each page is loaded to select the stylesheet:

```js
let defaultStyle = "light.css"
let chosenStyle = sessionStorage.getItem("jugglingSiteTheme");

// Setting Style
chosenStyleLink = document.createElement("link");
chosenStyleLink.rel = "stylesheet";
chosenStyleLink.id = "pagestyle";
    /* If there is a saved theme, use that, else use default */
chosenStyleLink.href = (chosenStyle ? chosenStyle : defaultStyle);
document.head.appendChild(chosenStyleLink);
// Done setting style
```

And a function to swap the stylesheet:

```js
function swapStyle(sheet)
{
    sessionStorage.setItem("jugglingSiteTheme", sheet);
    document.getElementById("pagestyle").setAttribute("href", sheet);
}
```

The problem is, when I reload the page or switch pages, it seems to load the page with default CSS before loading the CSS set by the first code block here. It flashes with the default CSS for just a brief second before loading correctly. Here is the `head` section of my html document where I source the javascript:

```js
<head>
    <title>
        Juggling Club: About Us
    </title>
    <script src="styles.js"></script>
</head>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Not sure if this would fix your issue, but why don't you put all the styles in the same css file and then just use the appropriate class on you html body tag, e.g. body.light

Comment: @VilleKoo but I need to determine what the appropriate class is, so I think i have to use javascript. Is that not true?

Comment: Yeah, you're right about the implementation, i just meant that putting all the css in one file eliminates the need for an extra http request :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can load both the dark and light CSS files on your page and based on the new `prefers-color-scheme` in CSS, the browser will load that CSS file on the highest priority and the other file on the lowest priority.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/dark.css" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/light.css" media="(prefers-color-scheme: no-preference), (prefers-color-scheme: light)">
<!-- The main stylesheet -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

If `prefers-color-scheme` is not supported, fall back to light mode. In this case, light.css will be downloaded with `highest` priority.

```html
<script>
  if (!window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme)').matches) {
    document.documentElement.style.display = 'none';
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML(
        'beforeend',
        '<link rel="stylesheet" href="/light.css" onload="document.documentElement.style.display = ``">'
    );
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. What should go in `style.css`, and what is `prefers-color-scheme`?

Comment: If you don't have style.css then just load your both light and dark theme. I wrote `style.css` assuming you have a base style file and then two files for two themes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-color-scheme you can read about `prefers-color-scheme` here. It is basically a new feature added in CSS which can detect your system theme and based on that you set the theme of your site without the need for the user to hit a button to set the theme.

Comment: Ah, I see, however I was planning on having more detailed ways to set light vs dark, such as looking at user's localtime and setting light during the day and dark during the night, which that option doesn't support. So I guess there is still no way to fix this if I am setting the theme with javascript, since it will always run the script after the page loads.

Comment: You can add the JS inside the `<head></head>` tag and above the `<link>` tag for your CSS and add it an IIFE `(() => { ... })`.

Comment: It still seems to flash, though it seems faster and less frequent.

Answer (score 0):

The flash will happen as you are changing the stylesheet using JS and the default css loads before any script runs in the page.

But to avoid the flashing you can hide the page/ `body` content in the default css:

```
body {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And then in your theme stylesheet you can override the default style of visibility for `body`:

```
body {
 visibility: visible;
}
```

Hopefully, it will help you to prevent page flashing.

Comment: It seems to still be flashing, at least when using the dark theme, because when the page content is hidden but the CSS hasn't loaded, the screen is white.

Comment: The page is white because it is the default behavior of the browser. Before your page is loaded what you see is set by the browser. I think you can't do anything about that

Comment: One way to solve your issue is to make your site a SPA

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Convert your site to a React or Angular application

Comment: Oh. I'm trying to stick with just plain javascript and html, so that doesn't work for me, but thanks. But when I just set the stylesheet with a normal `link` tag, there is no flash, even when I switch to a page with a totally different stylesheet. Is this just because that loads first, whereas the javascript doesn't run until after the page has loaded?

Comment: Yes, your `css` will always before the `scripts`

Comment: Ok, so I guess I will just have to live with it. Thanks anyway.